# How to use android.media.midi in qpython?

Tags: android, qpython

How to use android.media.midi (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary.html) in QPython? Or how to work with midi in QPython (over usb, bluetooth). Thanks.

Edit: Or how use android.media.midi in python under termux?